# How can I make an EBS volume with a raw image bootable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to create an AMI from the raw images here:

http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/xenial/release/ubuntu-16.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.tar.gz

Here are the steps I'm taking:

1. Log into existing Ubuntu instance
2. Create, attach and mount the EBS volume
3. Download and extract image from cloud-images.ubuntu.com

4.
dd extracted image to attached volume /dev/xvdf

```
time sudo dd if=cloudimg-amd64.img of=/dev/xvdf conv=sync,noerror bs=1M
```

5. Detach volume, snapshot volume, create ami from snapshot

When I try to launch the AMI it fails with hard disk not bootable.

In addition to the above also tried using ec2-import-instance

```
  ec2-import-instance --architecture x86_64 --platform Linux --bucket mybucket --volume-size 5 --availability-zone us-east-1d -O ID-REMOVED -W ID-REMOVED -o ID-REMOVED -w ID-REMOVED --instance-type t2.micro --format raw xenial.img  --subnet subnet-12345678
```

but it appears --format raw actually doeesn't mean what it says, it doesn't create a bootable AMI and fails with

```
 Client.Unsupported: No valid MBR found. Please verify your image.
```

So how can I manually make a volume bootable (or create an AMI) from a raw image obtained from cloud-images.ubuntu.com?

Note:  I need to be able to do this from the RAW EC2 images at cloud-images.ubuntu.com, copying existing AMI's is not an option.

I also tried aws ec2 import-image method, that doesn't work either for any format.

Comment: *"copying existing AMI's is not an option"*  Well, that doesn't seem to make sense.  What do you think [these **official Ubuntu** AMIs](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/) are?  They're what you're trying to do, built by Ubuntu engineers.

Comment: For starters I want to reduce the image size, so yes it's not an option because you can't reduce the size of an existing AMI, you can only launch the same or larger size.  Secondly, I will have custom raw images, I'm just using the official ones for testing right now.

Comment: You should clarify the question.  It seems like you have some valid reasons, which was not at all initially apparent. Your question, as it stands now, is venturing into the fringes of [XY](http://xyproblem.info) territory,  because it is not about your actual (ultimate goal) problem, but about a single step in yout attempted solution, and the specifics are likely a distraction to others as they were to me.  Help is best provided when the full picture is available.

Comment: It's true, you can't directly reduce the image size, but I believe there are is a workaround involving detaching the boot volume, attach it elsewhere, shrink the filesystem, repartition to match (with unpartitioned space at the end), `dd` the result onto a new, smaller EBS volume, attach that, and boot -- you should be able to create a new, smaller AMI from the resulting machine.

Comment: You're right, the question wasn't very clear because that's what happens with no sleep, two kids causing hell and a migraine.  Next time I'll get divorced, ditch the kids, take painkillers and hire a masseur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using the Amazon CLI, specifically this command:

```
 aws ec2 import-snapshot
```

Then I created a volume with a bootable partition and copied the snapshot to it.

RAW images must be imported as snapshots.

Comment: Hi @user2001109, Can you please eloborate the steps. I am also trying to create AMI from OS disk image, but I am getting error while booting EC2 instance : "Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,0)" Please go through my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50505025/changes-required-to-create-ami-from-os-disk-ebs-volume-manually